# Finding generalized eigenvalues with linear constraints

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I have a generalized eigenvalue problem
$$Mx = \lambda Bx$$
with the additional constraint that $Cx=0$, where $M$ and $B$ are positive-definite and $C$ is a sparse and rectangular.

Is there a simple way of solving for the generalized spectrum $(\lambda,x)$? Conceptually, if I had a way of computing a basis for the nullspace $N$ of $C$, I could simply solve instead the unconstrained generalized eigenvalue problem
$$N^TMNy = \lambda N^TBNy$$
for which I have code. However, since $C$ is sparse, computing this $N$ (using, e.g., a SVD) is expensive and I would like to avoid it if a different, more efficient reformulation of the problem is possible.

Comment: You can try to solve an augmented problem $$\begin{bmatrix}M&C^T \\ C&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=\lambda\begin{bmatrix}B&0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$$ if your code can handle a singular matrix on the "right-hand side".

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Good thought, I'll look into that.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel What if the right-hand side of the constrain is non-zero. Say, $Cx = b$.

Comment: @user7530, There are sparse QR methods that are efficient and store the factors efficiently (for example in matlab).

Answer (score 0):

If $Cx=b$ with $b \neq 0$ you can make a change of variable $u=x-x'$ where $x'$ satisfies $Cx'=b$. Then the constraint in the new variable $u$ becomes $Cu=0$. Then the augmented problem becomes
$\begin{bmatrix}M&C^T \\ C&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u \\ z\end{bmatrix}=\lambda\begin{bmatrix}B&0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u \\ z\end{bmatrix}$. Theta is essentially the same problem. The eigenvalues do not change, and the eigenvectors are the same but must be interpreted as relative to $x'$.